# Problems with execvp

Tags: c++, shell, execvp

I'm trying to create a simple shell. Here's what I've done so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

void execute(std::vector<char *> instructions)
{
    auto pid = fork();
    int status;

    if (pid < 0) {
        std::cout << "Fork error occured!" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        if(execvp(instructions[0], instructions.data()) < 0) {
            std::cout << "Command Not Found" << std::endl;
            exit(1);
        }
    } else {
        while (wait(&status) != pid);
    }
}

std::vector<char *>  splitter(std::string input)
{
    std::istringstream iss(input);
    std::vector<std::string> tokens{std::istream_iterator<std::string>{iss},
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>{}};
    std::vector<char *> instructions(tokens.size());
    for (auto i = 0; i != tokens.size(); ++i) {
        instructions[i] = &tokens[i][0];
    }
    return instructions;
}

int main()
{
    std::string input;

    while (1) {
        std::cout << "[cmd]:";
        getline(std::cin, input);
        if (input == "exit") exit(0);
        std::vector<char *> instructions = splitter(input);
        execute(instructions);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I run the code and enter "ls" several times I get varying results:

```
[cmd]:ls
Assignment IV
[cmd]:ls
Command Not Found
[cmd]:ls
Assignment IV
[cmd]:ls
Assignment IV
[cmd]:ls
Command Not Found
[cmd]:pwd
/Users/diveafall/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Assignment_IV-grxcoesjdabjvoenxkaprouhexuh/Build/Products/Debug
[cmd]:
```

I have no idea why this happens. I suppose my string splitting function is far from ideal. Can you please help me fix it? Also, if you have any tips please feel free to give them. I'm a noob and I'll appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: When `execvp` fails, it will help your debugging to include the arguments passed in the error message, to ensure you are making the call you think you are making.

Comment: I'm not sure but I have a feeling that your `splitter` function doesn't quite work as you intend. It returns a vector of pointers but those pointers point to a local variable `tokens` (or rather, it's contents). They go out of scope when the function ends. Wouldn't accessing those pointers after the function returns have undefined behaviour?